# How to generate m3u8 from a list of files in ffmpeg?

Tags: ffmpeg

Let's say I have this list of files:
audios:

```
file1.mp3 //audiotrack 1
file2.mp3 //audiotrack 2
file3.mp3 //audiotrack 3
```

subtitles:

```
file1.vtt //subtitle 1
file2.vtt //subtitle 2
file3.vtt //subtitle 3
```

videos:

```
file1_320x280.mp4 //video quality 1
file2_640x11024.mp4 //video quality 2
file3_1200x1600.mp4 //video quality 3
```

how to convert with FFMPEG all this files to .TS fragments with a m3u8 file?

also will the video.js HLS extension allow the user to choose the quality?

Answer (score 0):

I am not a professional in this sphere, but here is how I handle it.

Refferences:
[Perfect example of manifest you want.](https://bitdash-a.akamaihd.net/content/sintel/hls/playlist.m3u8)

Firstly:

Make .m3u8 playlists for each video

```
ffmpeg -i file1_320x280.mp4 -profile:v baseline -level 3.0 -start_number 0 -hls_time 10 -hls_list_size 0 -f hls file1_320x280.m3u8

ffmpeg -i file2_640x11024.mp4 -profile:v baseline -level 3.0 -start_number 0 -hls_time 10 -hls_list_size 0 -f hls file2_640x11024.m3u8

ffmpeg -i file3_1200x1600.mp4 -profile:v baseline -level 3.0 -start_number 0 -hls_time 10 -hls_list_size 0 -f hls file3_1200x1600.m3u8
```

Secondly:

Make .m3u8 playlists for each audio (I use the same command as for video)

```
ffmpeg -i file1.mp3 -profile:v baseline -level 3.0 -start_number 0 -hls_time 10 -hls_list_size 0 -f hls file1_320x280.m3u8

ffmpeg -i file2.mp3 -profile:v baseline -level 3.0 -start_number 0 -hls_time 10 -hls_list_size 0 -f hls file2.m3u8

ffmpeg -i file3.mp3 -profile:v baseline -level 3.0 -start_number 0 -hls_time 10 -hls_list_size 0 -f hls file3.m3u8
```

Than I manually create .m3u8 files for each subtitle with such content:

```
#EXTM3U
#EXT-X-TARGETDURATION: <<VIDEO RUNTIME HERE>>
#EXT-X-VERSION:3
#EXT-X-MEDIA-SEQUENCE:1
#EXT-X-PLAYLIST-TYPE:VOD
#EXTINF: <<VIDEO RUNTIME HERE>>,
file1.vtt
#EXT-X-ENDLIST
```

Where #EXTINF and #EXT-X-TARGETDURATION is duration of a video in seconds.
For example (lets assume that video duration is 00:14:47):

sub1.m3u8:

```
#EXTM3U
#EXT-X-TARGETDURATION:887
#EXT-X-VERSION:3
#EXT-X-MEDIA-SEQUENCE:1
#EXT-X-PLAYLIST-TYPE:VOD
#EXTINF:887.0,
file1.vtt
#EXT-X-ENDLIST
```

sub2.m3u8:

```
#EXTM3U
#EXT-X-TARGETDURATION:887
#EXT-X-VERSION:3
#EXT-X-MEDIA-SEQUENCE:1
#EXT-X-PLAYLIST-TYPE:VOD
#EXTINF:887.0,
file2.vtt
#EXT-X-ENDLIST
```

sub3.m3u8:

```
#EXTM3U
#EXT-X-TARGETDURATION:887
#EXT-X-VERSION:3
#EXT-X-MEDIA-SEQUENCE:1
#EXT-X-PLAYLIST-TYPE:VOD
#EXTINF:887.0,
file3.vtt
#EXT-X-ENDLIST
```

Finally, I manually create master.m3u8 file with following content for this example:

```
#EXTM3U

#EXT-X-MEDIA:TYPE=AUDIO,GROUP-ID="stereo",LANGUAGE="lang",NAME="Some audio name",DEFAULT=YES,AUTOSELECT=YES,URI="file1.m3u8"
#EXT-X-MEDIA:TYPE=AUDIO,GROUP-ID="stereo",LANGUAGE="lang2",NAME="Some audio name",DEFAULT=NO,AUTOSELECT=YES,URI="file2.m3u8"
#EXT-X-MEDIA:TYPE=AUDIO,GROUP-ID="stereo",LANGUAGE="lang3",NAME="Some audio name",DEFAULT=NO,AUTOSELECT=YES,URI="file3.m3u8"

#EXT-X-MEDIA:TYPE=SUBTITLES,GROUP-ID="subs",NAME="Deutsch",DEFAULT=NO,AUTOSELECT=YES,FORCED=NO,LANGUAGE="de",URI="sub1.m3u8"
#EXT-X-MEDIA:TYPE=SUBTITLES,GROUP-ID="subs",NAME="English",DEFAULT=YES,AUTOSELECT=YES,FORCED=NO,LANGUAGE="en",URI="sub2.m3u8"
#EXT-X-MEDIA:TYPE=SUBTITLES,GROUP-ID="subs",NAME="Espanol",DEFAULT=NO,AUTOSELECT=YES,FORCED=NO,LANGUAGE="es",URI="sub3.m3u8"

#EXT-X-STREAM-INF:PROGRAM-ID=1,BANDWIDTH=258157,CODECS="avc1.4d400d,mp4a.40.2",AUDIO="stereo",RESOLUTION=320x280,SUBTITLES="subs"
file1_320x280.m3u8
#EXT-X-STREAM-INF:PROGRAM-ID=1,BANDWIDTH=520929,CODECS="avc1.4d4015,mp4a.40.2",AUDIO="stereo",RESOLUTION=file2_640x11024,SUBTITLES="subs"
file2_640x11024.m3u8
#EXT-X-STREAM-INF:PROGRAM-ID=1,BANDWIDTH=1144430,CODECS="avc1.4d401f,mp4a.40.2",AUDIO="stereo",RESOLUTION=1200x1600,SUBTITLES="subs"
file3_1200x1600.m3u8
```